# Firebase Listener on the Background Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener, android-workmanager

So, I wanted to use a Firebase Listener in the background because there's some code I need to trigger while the app is closed based on Database values. I thought I could just throw the listener on a Service, however reading the docs looks like Services are no longer a good option because of how the OS works in recent versions.

I found about the WorkManager class which supposedly is the best new option to implement background code and it looks fine and all however the 15 minutes minimum time for periodic jobs is way to much time for what I need.

So I was wondering what could be the best practice possible to use a Firebase Listener on the background? Or should I just abandon the idea of using a listener on the background at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can't force a listener to stay live while the app has been backgrounded.  This is because Android can (and will) kill the app process when the user isn't using it any more.  Your connection to the database will be lost.

You could use WorkManager to wake your app periodically to check the database, but that doesn't sound like what you want.

The preferred solution is to use Firebase Cloud Messaging from a backend you control to ping the app when you know there is new data it's interested in.

Comment: Yeah I read about using FCM from a backend and stuff, the thing is the code I need to trigger based on the database is native to android. To be more exact, there's a AlarmManager I need to turn off based on a variable in Firebase. And I suppose you can only do that from the phone itself. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Yeah, FCM will ping your app, and you can use the payload of that message to determine what code to run on your client.  You can use Cloud Functions to trigger code on the backend when the database changes, then send the message from there.  This is a very common use case.

Comment: So I could actually turn the AlarmManager off this way? Do you know of any examples I could look into? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think you need AlarmManager at all.  Simply do the work with the database in response to the incoming message.  You could schedule that work to run ASAP with WorkManager.